# How do I find and remove white specks from an image using SciPy/NumPy?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I have a series of images which serve as my raw data which I am trying to prepare for publication. These images have a series of white specks randomly throughout which I would like to replace with the average of some surrounding pixels.

I cannot post images, but the following code should produce a PNG that approximates the issue that I'm trying to correct:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imsave

random_array = np.random.random_sample((512,512))

random_array[random_array < 0.999] *= 0.25

imsave('white_specs.png', random_array)
```

While this should produce an image with a similar *distribution* of the specks present in my raw data, my images *do not* have specks uniform in intensity, and some of the specks are more than a single pixel in size (though none of them are more than 2). Additionally, there are spots on my image that I *do not* want to alter that were *intentionally* saturated during data acquisition for the purpose of clarity when presented: these spots are approximately 10 pixels in diameter.

In principle, I could write something to look for pixels whose value exceeds a certain threshold then check them against the average of their nearest neighbors. However, I assume what I'm ultimately trying to achieve is not an uncommon action in image processing, and I very much suspect that there is some SciPy functionality that will do this without having to reinvent the wheel. My issue is that I am not familiar enough with the formal aspects/vocabulary of image processing to really know what I should be looking for. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The operation you're looking for is a _despeckle_ operation. basically instead of taking the mean of the pixel with the surrounding pixels, you take the median (of the luminosity). There's a good example [here](https://github.com/niroyb/Despeckle/blob/master/despeckle.py).

Comment: There's another approach [here](http://www.websupergoo.com/helpie/source/2-effects/despeckle.htm) that  despeckles by analyzing the standard deviation, then just uses a mean filter if the standard deviation is low enough.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Another user recommended a SciPy built-in that did just the trick.

Comment: Yep, I upvoted that one, since that was precisely what you were looking for. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could simply try a median filter with a small kernel size,

```
from scipy.ndimage import median_filter

filtered_array = median_filter(random_array, size=3)
```

which will remove the specks without noticeably changing  the original image.

A median filter is well suited for such tasks since it will better preserve features in your original image with high spatial frequency, when compared for instance to a simple moving average filter.

By the way, if your images are experimental (i.e. noisy) applying a non-aggressive median filter (such as the one above) never hurts as it allows to attenuate the noise as well.